# How do I correctly escape this search string for Perl pie

Tags: regex, perl

I use this classic perl one liner to replace strings in multiple files recursively

```
perl -pi -e 's/oldstring/newstring/g' `grep -irl oldstring *`
```

But this has failed me as I want to find the string:

```
'$user->primaryorganisation->id'
```

and replace with

```
$user->primaryorganisation->id
```

I can't seem to escape the string correctly for the line to run successfully.

Any help gratefully received!

Comment: You can save yourself one layer of escapes here by using a source file to replace the `-e` code: `perl -pi source.pl ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one. Lots of escapes. Go with TLPs suggestion and use a source file.

```
perl -pi -e "s/'\\\$user->primaryorganisation->id'/\\\$user->primaryorganisation->id/g" `grep -irl  "'\$user->primaryorganisation->id'" *`
```

Explanation:

- three backslashes: the first two tell the shell to produce a literal backslash; the thrid one escapes the `$` for the shell; that makes `\$` for Perl, which needs the backslash to escape the variable interpolation
- double quotes `"` to put single quotes `'` inside them
- one backslash and a dollar `\$` for grep so the shell passes on a literal dollar sign

Comment: Explanations deserve extra credit. Give a fish vs. teach to fish.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to represent a single quote in a perl but can't because the one-liner uses single quotes itself, you can use `\047`, the octal code for single quote. So, this should work:

```
s/\047(\$user->primaryorganisation->id)\047/$1/g
```

I recommend *Minimal Perl* by Maher for more-than-you-wanted-to-know about the art of one-lining perl.

Answer (score 0):

To produce

```
...'...
```

you can generically use

```
'...'\''...'
```

As such,

```
s/'(\$user->primaryorganisation->id)'/$1/g
```

becomes

```
's/'\''(\$user->primaryorganisation->id)'\''/$1/g'
```

so

```
find -type f \
    -exec perl -i -pe's/'\''(\$user->primaryorganisation->id)'\''/$1/g' {} +
```